# model's fetch does not work

Tags: backbone.js

Here is body of my model

```
urlRoot: '/users',

parse: function(response) {
   return response.User;
}
```

Here is what is returned when I type `/users/1` in my browser:

```
{"User":{"id":"1","created":"2013-02-13 09:22:42","modified":"2013-02-13 09:22:42","username":"somesuername","password":"","role":"somerole","token":null,"token_expiration":null}}
```

So the api works.
When I execute this:

```
this.model.id = 1;
this.model.fetch({ success: function(user){
                        console.log(user);    
                   }}); // this.model is instance of my model
```

I get in console:

```
d {cid: "c4", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
_changing: false
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
    __proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c4"
id: Array[1]
__proto__: e
```

So the result was successful by model didn't fetch any data - am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

`Backbone.Model` stores the data inside the `attributes` property. From [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes):

> The attributes property is the internal hash containing the model's state — usually (but not necessarily) a form of the JSON object representing the model data on the server. It's often a straightforward serialization of a row from the database, but it could also be client-side computed state.
>
> Please use set to update the attributes instead of modifying them directly.

Try expanding the `attributes` node in the console object inspector, and you should see your data.

Comment: no - sorry I pasted console output in bad format - after expanding attributes only this line `__proto__: Object` is visible. no attributes - I know how it works because my collection works ok but model doesn't...

Comment: @user606521 Oops, didn't notice that. Have you inspected the response in your browser's developer tools and verified that the server is indeed responding with data?

Comment: @user606521, also, interestingly your model `id` in the inspector is an `Array[1]`. Don't know how that could come about, but I'm pretty sure that's related your problem.

Comment: Thanks - I did what you told me and I found out that the ajax request was to /users not /users/id - it was because in parent model I overrided function `url`. Thanks!